# Navigation betwen the 4 desktops of Unity?

Tags: unity

I love Unity so far. But since last update (of what? I don't know. It happened after i restarted my PC), Navigation between the 4 desktops has changed.
I can still click on an app in the launcher to move to the desktop where the app is located (which i love) - but when arrived on this other desktop - Unity shows me a 200px*100px map of all desktops for 1 sec... which is pure visual pollution if you want my opinion.

Can I prevent Unity from displaying this 'map' when i slide from one desktop to another using the launcher icons?

Also, I'm searching for a list of key shortcuts to navigate between desktops if it exists...

Thank you very much in advance.
DenisefromFrance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Disabling Previews

You can do it using **Compiz Config Settings Manager**.

- **Install Compiz Config Settings Manager**

  - Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
  - Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

- **Changing Settings**

  - Open *Compiz Config Settings Manager* by searching the same in the dash or from the terminal using `ccsm` command.
  - Goto *Desktop > Desktop Wall*, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

- Uncheck *Show Viewport Switcher Preview* and *Show Live Viewport Previews*, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

- Close *Compiz Config Settings Manager*.

To revert back to the default settings, just check the two checkboxes again.

## Shortcuts for navigating

To navigate around the workspaces, the controls are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>: Switch to the left workspace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>: Switch to the right workspace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Switch to the upper workspace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>: Switch to the workspace below

You can see the full list of shortcuts by holding the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (also shown in the screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Green7 for this so complete answer!!! Have a great day!